# Having trouble debugging error message libicui18n.so.62: no such directory of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu

When I run my rails server I'm met with this error

```
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.62: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[ExecJS::RuntimeError on my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd6bc.png)

I tried:

```
$ brew install icu4c
```

and reinstalling ruby through rbenv to no success.

Why does is this happening?  I understand it can't locate, but I'm confused by its purpose and why its a problem now.